# How much delay does two sequential linux commands have if they are run as a shellscript?

Tags: linux, shell, delay

I have two commands A and B. I want to execute them together, but the only feasible way in linux is to use &. That is,

```
$ A &
$ B
```

I don't expect 0 delay two commands, but approximately, how much should I expect? In milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds range? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Run a command that ouput the current time in miliseconds to different file

Comment: Or try GNU Parallel to actually run them simultaneously https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo Outputting the file takes extra time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any answer to this question is going to be dependant on what exactly the system is doing at any given time. For example:

- What kernel scheduler you're using (their latencies differ)
- What processes are you're running (they all compete for time, and the scheduler may not choose you're processes as early as you'd like)

And probably a thousand other things. For this reason, *run this test yourself*. Also note that the following could be wrong in many subtle ways, since I'm not very knowledgable about getting the best performance possible out of `bash` (well, `zsh` strictly speaking, since that's my login shell).

---

With this in mind, I devised a simple way to test this. GNU date has a way to show *nanoseconds* (yes, you read that correctly). Thus, to get a bunch of data, all you need to do is:

```
get_starting_diff() {
    date +%N & date +%N
}

# 5,000 iterations is probably good enough statistically
for iteration in $(seq 1 5000); do
    get_starting_diff
done > times
```

This will (besides chewing up *a lot* of PIDs) produce 10,000 line file, with the timing information in it. You can then use the following Python (v3.4) script to get an idea of what you're average timing difference is:

```
def pairwise(iterator):
    "Takes an iterator and extracts sequential pairs from it"
    pair = []
    for item in iterator:
        pair.append(item)
        if len(pair) == 2:
            yield pair
            pair = []

diffs = []
with open('times') as data:
    for start1, start2 in pairwise(data):
        diffs.append(int(start2) - int(start1))

diffs.sort()
median = diffs[len(diffs) // 2]
mean = sum(diffs) / len(diffs)

print("The median difference is", median / 1000000, "milliseconds")
print("The mean difference is", mean / 1000000, "milliseconds")
```

On my (Ubuntu 13.10, Linux 3.12.0-997-generic) system, this gives me:

```
The median difference is 1.077483 milliseconds
The mean difference is 3.680928442211055 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running parallel tasks. Make no assumptions about what order they will run in. They could run in any order. B could even run to completion before A starts. Then the next time you run it you could get completely different results.